# alternative to through2-map in node.js [related to learnyounode]

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, request, response

#### Problem i am solving:

Write an HTTP server that receives only POST requests and converts incoming POST body characters to upper-case and returns it to the client.

Your server should listen on the port provided by the first argument to your program.

#### My Solution

```
var http = require('http');
var map = require('through2-map')


http.createServer(function(request,response){

    if (request.method == 'POST'){
    request.pipe(map(function (chunk) {
      return chunk.toString().toUpperCase();
    })).pipe(response);



    }

}).listen(process.argv[2]);
```

Can i implement is without using through2-map ?
My crippling solution which doesn't work:

```
 request.on('data',function(data){
     body += data.toString();
     console.log(body);
 });
 request.pipe(body.toUpperCase()).pipe(response);
```

Can i do the real hard way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 2nd snippet, `body.toUpperCase()` will act immediately before any of the `'data'` events have actually occurred. The call to `.on()` only adds the event handler so it will be called, but doesn't yet call it.

You can use the [`'end'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end), along with `'data'`, to wait for all `data` chunks to be received, ready to be uppercased:

```
request.on('data', function (data) {
    body += data.toString();
});

request.on('end', function () {
    response.end(body.toUpperCase());
});
```

Note: Be sure that `body` is being declared and assigned an initial value:

```
var body = '';

response.on('data', ...);

// ...
```

Comment: thanks, can i use pipe with request as i use with through2-map ?
Also, can you give suggestion for title of post, seems like people are downvoting !

Comment: @igaurav You can [`.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) if you use a [`stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) to perform the uppercasing. You can define your own [`stream.Transform`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) for that, which is essentially what `through2-map` is defining for you.